# Why is the order of opacity declaration important in this two-phase fade-in?

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-transitions, opacity

I have written a two-phase fading button. I have noticed that the order the opacity states are declared, is important.

This CSS works:

```
.item .btn-remove {
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

.item:hover .btn-remove {
  opacity: .25;
}

.item .btn-remove:hover {
  /* works here */
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Versus the version that does not work:

```
.item .btn-remove {
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

.item .btn-remove:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.item:hover .btn-remove {
  opacity: .25;
}
```

I can see that the order of declaration makes sense, but do not understand why this would make a difference as the rules are not conflicting (as far as my understanding of CSS thus far goes).

Please see my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/defayeke/r2mtbjbn/) for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All ancestors of an element that matches `:hover` will also match `:hover`. Although `:hover` is a CSS selector, this is specified in the HTML spec, not Selectors. From [section 4.14.2 of W3C HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/disabled-elements.html#pseudo-classes):

> The `:hover` pseudo-class is defined to match an element "while the user *designates* an element with a pointing device". For the purposes of defining the `:hover` pseudo-class only, an HTML user agent must consider an element as being one that the user *designates* if it is:
>
> - An element that the user indicates using a pointing device.
> - An element that has a descendant that the user indicates using a pointing device.

Therefore the `.item:hover .btn-remove` rule does apply even when `.btn-remove` itself matches `:hover` (i.e. when `.btn-remove` is the element that is being designated). In other words, the two CSS rules do in fact overlap with one another, thus creating a conflict.

Comment: ...and they have same specificity. However I can see this with another attribute (let's say background color) but with opacity (at least with Chrome 44) it works _as intended_ regardless order. Weird.